# html5 local storage for offline viewing

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a folder, which contains html files, images, stylesheets, and js. 
I have uploaded it to the server and when i open it on ipad, all the content should get stored on iPad for offline viewing. How can this be done using webstorage / local storage? 
I tried with offline cache but it has its limit of 5MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webserver has to support this by adding

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

to your .htaccess or server config.

then you need a manifest file, which says the client "store these files locally". Just create a blank file call it something like "data.manifest" and add this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE
index.html
style.css
etc..
```

There are many more things you can do in this manifest file. I consider using Google or the search for this.

At least you have to edit your `<html>`-tag for your manifest file to your site.

```
<html manifest="/data.manifest" />
```

That's it. The browser should ask you whether it should store data locally.

Comment: i tried with it, but the limit is 5MB, and my data size is 50MB

Comment: Well, then you have to shrink your data or you have to wait for apple to fix that in the future. Btw, 50MB of Data for a single page is really huge. Ever thought about PhoneGap?

Comment: The total size of the folder is 50MB, and i ve read it can be done through Web SQL Databases, any idea mate?

Comment: Never worked with the local storage database, but I think there are a few tutorials out there. You just have to store your text in that db (pictures too, maybe) and hope it will reduce the size of your folder

Answer (score 2):

You have to split your app in two. A downloader and the actual app.

The downloader will download the required files once and save it to localstorage/webstorage. Once saved your app can be loaded from local copy directly. The downloader part will be saved using cache manifest mechanism.

I am currently developing an app which works in the same way.

Note: JS and CSS files can be saved directly to localstorage, but for images you have to convert them to base64 and then use them. Watch out for the base64 size limitations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme